# Complex Plane Rotation Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Let a, b, and c be complex numbers. Let $a_1$ be the image of a when it is rotated $90^\circ$ clockwise around b. Let $a_2$ be the image of $a_1$ when it is rotated $90^\circ$ counter-clockwise around c.

[image]

Then $a_2$ can be written in the form $a_2 = pa + qb + rc$ for some complex numbers $p, q$, and $r$. Find $p^2 + q^2 + r^2$.

I tried to use the general formula for complex rotation $(a-b)e^{i\theta}+b$, but kept making some error that I could not find.  Could I get  some help?  Thanks!

EDIT: I did $(((a-b)(-i)+b)-c)i+c=a_2$, then reduced this to $a+(-1+i)b+(1-i)c$.  However, $1^2+(-1+i)^2+(1-i)^2=3-4i$ is incorrect.  What went wrong?

Comment: Can you put your attempt here, telling where you are getting stuck or why you think you are making an error? I tried, and it seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: center of rotation around b and c are differerent.

Comment: $1^2+(-1+i)^2+(1-i)^2\ne 3-4i$

Comment: Your computation of $p$, $q$, and $r$ looks good. Your computation of $p^2+q^2+r^2$, not so good.

Comment: I got it, thanks everyone!